# Basic Question about function notation

Tags: functions, proof-explanation

What exactly does it mean and why is it important?

$\forall f: $N $\longrightarrow$ R

Like it says for all functions f that map from the naturals to the reals, but I don't understand why it is important and what the meaning is.

Comment: What is the context of this notation?

Comment: a proof involving big oh

Comment: I think you should write down more details so people could understand your question.  I suggest you write down the whole problem and proof here.  Then point out the part you are having trouble with.